# Pass a select value in ajax

Tags: html, ajax, select

I'm trying to pass a select value in my ajax function.

my html code:

```
    <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" class="selectUser">
                    <?php foreach($logs as $key => $value){ ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $value['username'];?>"><?php echo $value['username'];     ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select>
```

and my JS code:

```
   $('select.selectUser').change(function(){
        alert('Select field value has changed to' + $('select.selectUser').val());

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "Panier/loadPanier",
            data: {username: $('select.selectUser').val()},
            success: function(result){
                var data1 = JSON.parse(result);
                alert(data1.username) ;
            },

        });

    });
```

but the first `alert('Select field value has changed to' + $('select.selectUser').val());` is not generating any alert and I'm not getting any error in my console.

Can you tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Try using just the class `$(".selectUser")` additionally try checking whether the option tags are actually having a value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added `two class` attributes to the `select` element - `class="form-control"` and 
`class="selectUser"`.

```
<select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" class="selectUser">
```

Therefore, it is ignoring your second class - `class="selectUser"`.

```js
$('select.selectUser').on('change', function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control selectUser" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
  <option value="1" selected="selected">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's try with `$('#exampleFormControlSelect1').on('change', function(){`

Comment: Could have been a comment